# 64-bit version of PyPlot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have been struggling to get a 64-bit version of PyPlot. I have found an [unofficial 64-bit version of matplotlib](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#matplotlib), but then when I `import matplotlib`, `pyplot` is not an attribute of `matplotlib`.

How can I get a 64-bit version of PyPlot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this isn't a dumb suggestion, but did you try `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`?  It is a submodule and you wouldn't normally be able to access it as an attribute of `matplotlib`.

Comment: Excellent, that worked! So why did that work, but not `import matplotlib` and then `matplotlib.pyploy`?

Comment: Is this the answer? Or what do you mean by "Yes!"

Comment: Yes, that's the answer. I was being "dumb" I guess. Or Python behaves somewhat unintuitively...

Comment: Sorry I wasn't meaning to call you dumb!  The distinction between modules and packages _is_ confusing, I don't really understand it fully myself but I think it's related to the `__init__.py` file (i.e. the stuff which is in there is what is visible after the import)

Comment: One reason is that `pyplot` is quite slow to import, and there are other things in `matplotlib`, so `matplotlib.pyplot` isn't imported by default when you import `matplotlib`.  The other reason is that importing `matplotlib` allows you to set the backend before importing `matplotlib.pyplot` (The backend can't be changed after `pyplot` has been imported).

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to 64bit-Python with third-party libraries relying on compiled code (like Numpy, Scipy and Matplotlib), the first question is: which operating system are you using?

- Linux, e.g., Debian: Just do `apt-get` or whatever, and you're done.
- Windows: Think twice if you really need 64bit, and if you do, better use a professionally supported version like [EPD](http://www.enthought.com/products/epd.php)

I made a couple of painful experiences when trying to maintain 64bit-Python manually on Windows.

For Mac I have no personal experience.

Comment: O.k. As the problem was much more trivial, please mark wim's answer as solution. I wish you good luck with your installation.